# Quarto inline math not displaying

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, docx, quarto

I am writing a quarto file with docx as output. I would like to insert inline math in the text. When I am using the visual editor it doesn't get displayed. Looking at the source, it is there, also in the output file it is rendered correctly. Does someone know how I could make it displayed also in the visual editor? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Julian, I do exactly as you put it, nevertheless it doesn't get shown. I only see my inline math when I insert it and the cursor is in the inserted inline math. As soon as I click out, it disappears in the visual mode. In source mode it is still visible

Comment: FYI, for anyone having this issue after making sure the math expression is correct, there's a decent chance updating RStudio will fix it, it just did for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert inline math in the text using `$...$`, e.g.

```
---
title: "test"
format: docx
---

## Inline Math

Equation $x^2$
```

which get rendered correctly and is also shown in the visual editor.

[image]

If you do not *add a space* behind the inline math code, it is displayed as raw code, i.e.
[image]